# SQL Self Join - Which Alias to Assign in the WHERE Clause?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to understand what is the logic for assigning the table aliases in the `WHERE` clause.

Below in the much used example of the `employee` table, where `Supervisor Name` is created through an inner join.

The primary key in the table is `emp_id` and the foreign key is `emp_supv`

```
SELECT
    a.emp_id AS "Emp_ID",
    a.emp_name AS "Employee Name",
    b.emp_id AS "Supervisor ID",
    b.emp_name AS "Supervisor Name"
FROM employee a, employee b
WHERE a.emp_supv = b.emp_id
```

I really don't understand the `WHERE` clause...what's the logic of assigning alias `a` to `emp_supv`, and not to `emp_id`?

Comment: It's a comparison, not an assignment.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should start using explicit `JOIN` operators instead of the ancient, outdated and fragile implicit joins in the where clause.

Comment: @jarlh I don't think he/she actually meant that.

Answer (score 2):

It's like having 2 different tables.

Maybe it's easier to understand with an other alias

```
SELECT
    t_employee.emp_id AS "Emp_ID",
    t_employee.emp_name AS "Employee Name",
    t_supervisor.emp_id AS "Supervisor ID",
    t_supervisor.emp_name AS "Supervisor Name"
FROM employee t_employee , employee t_supervisor
WHERE t_employee.emp_supv = t_supervisor.emp_id
```

You seach in the Supervisor Table (t_supervisor) for a row with the **emp_id** of **emp_supv** stored in the Employee Table (t_employee)

Answer (score 0):

If the `WHERE` statement was:

```
 a.emp_id = b.emp_id
```

then you will be saying that the employee Id of both the supervisor and the employee is the same, so the data retrieved for the supervisor and the employee will be the same (e.g; Employee Name will be equal to Supervisor Name).

But If you mean why it was not like :

```
a.emp_id = b.emp_supv
```

Then the employee represented by the table `a` will be the supervisor of the employee represented by the table `b`  (Employee Name will be actually the supervisor name of the employee that has Id equal to `b.emp_id`)

Comment: Ok, thanks, I think I got this now. I was interested in the second case that you listed: a.emp_id = b.emp_supv.